# Send Outlook email using python win32com and flag as Follow-up

Tags: python, winapi, outlook, pywin32, win32com

How can I flag a sent email to followup with a reminder date if possible using win32com python library, my code below does send the email, but does not create the followup reminder.

**Code:**

```
import win32com.client as win32   

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
#attachment1 = "x:\\report.htm"
attachment1 = "c:\\installAgent.log"
mail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment1)
mail.To = "obama@hotmail.com"   
mail.Subject = "test"
mail.HtmlBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>' #this field is optional
mail.FlagRequest = "Follow up";
mail.Display(True)
mail.send
```

Comment: `.FlagRequest = "Follow up"` & `.FlagDueBy = DateAdd("d", 3, Date)` for due date 3 days from today

Comment: do you mind sharing the function Dateadd

Comment: this is receipient receive follow up, how can i make this follow up for myself, i.e. the sender

Comment: Oh, I mis-understood your question, try using reminderSet & reminderTime

Comment: I get the following error   File "O365.py", line 12, in <module>
  mail.reminderSet  = "Follow up"
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 581, in __setattr__
  raise AttributeError("Property '%s.%s' can not be set." % (self._username_, attr))
tributeError: Property 'CreateItem.reminderSet' can not be set.

Comment: managed to fix the issue below, but this is just creating a reminder, i would like to flag the item for followup- this then would show up in the tasks list

Comment: by setting `mail.FlagRequest` and 'mail.FlagDueBy` after `mail.send`, does this fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a reminder in two ways:

1. Set a bell to go off in one week
2. Set the flag date to one week later (will not prompt a reminder but this is a good way to keep track of tasks)

`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import win32com.client as win32   

# Set the reminder to 7 days from now
reminder_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

mail.TaskStartDate = reminder_time  # flag start date
mail.TaskDueDate = reminder_time    # flag due date

mail.FlagDueBy = reminder_time   # reminder bell
mail.FlagIcon = 6  # orange flag
mail.FlagStatus = 2

# Save and close the email
mail.Save()
mail.Close(0)
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).